# pytest is running methods twice

Tags: python-2.7, pytest, fixtures

I have a problem when running the test methods on two different modules.
I have created suite function in a different module and defined it as a fixture.

On the two test classes, I have entered the created fixture, to use it as setup function just once.

For each test method, I have created setup and teardown methods.
When the test methods of the first module are run, the test from the other class (second module) is starting in the first class and then are run again in the second class. So the test methods in the second class are run twice, once from the first class in the first module and then from the second class in the second module.

I want to run the test methods once per class or module, and not to be run twice.

Can someone help me to get a solution?

PS: I use for the suite fixture the parameter scope='session' (tried with the module is the same)!

Example (conftest.py):

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def suite():
    print "start application"
    open_app()
```

Example (test.py):

```
    def setup_method(self, method):
        if method.__name__ == 'test_1':
            pass
        elif method.__name__ == 'test_2':
            pass
        else:
            print "test method not found"

    def teardown_method(self, method):
        print "teardown methods"



    def test_1(self):
        pass

    def test_2(self):
        pass

    def test_3(self):
        pass

    def setup_test_3(self, testcase):
        print "this is only for the test methd: test_3"

    def teardown_test_3(self):
        print "cleanup state after running test method test_3"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the parameter to your setup and teardown functions and put the condition based on the class or method name or module name and act it accordingly.

for e.g:--

```
def setup_method(value):
    if value.__name__ == '<name of method from the module1>':
        pass
    elif value.__name__ == '<name of method from the module2>':
        pass
```

Comment: Thank you @nikhilesh_koshti. But if I have different test methods and different setup and teardown methods how to run them?

Comment: Can you please provide with the example?, it would be better if there is some code example you want.

Comment: I added an example of my code. There you can see that I have different test methods and I want to have a different setup & teardown method for every test method (not only one setup & teardown method for all test).

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem from my side,because as i think,the setup method or class are specific to the Test-class where it is defined,it will not affect the other Test class method in the module.    

The setup_class() and setup_method() are used only once  in the testclass of pytest.